# Computing Total Value of Checkbox Selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to figure out the best way to compute a total value based on selection of a combination of 5 different selections using checkboxes. Here is code example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Value 1" name="Value1" id="Value1">Value 1
<input type="checkbox" value="Value 2" name="Value2" id="Value2">Value 2
<input type="checkbox" value="Value 3" name="Value3" id="Value1">Value 3
<input type="checkbox" value="Value 4" name="Value4" id="Value1">Value 4
<input type="checkbox" value="Value 5" name="Value5" id="Value1">Value 5
<input type="checkbox" value="Total Value" name="TotalValue"
id="TotalValue">Total Value
```

Here are sample number values of the checkboxes:
Checkbox 1 - 100
Checkbox 2 - 125
Checkbox 3 - 150
Checkbox 4 - 175
Checkbox 5 - 200

So my goal is to come up with a number value for TotalValue based on the checkbox selections. For example, if Checkbox 2 and Checkbox 4 are selected, Total Value would be 300. So user can select a single checkbox or any combination of checkboxes. I could probably do it using javascript, but the code would be very cumbersome and long. So was wondering if there is a streamlined way to do it using jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all checkboxes in target div with `$("#mainDiv input:checkbox")` and use `.on("change")` event to calculate total value of checked inputs when any of them is changed. You can implement like following.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#mainDiv input:checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var totalValue = 0;
    $('#mainDiv :checked').each(function() {
        totalValue += parseInt(($(this).val()));
    });
    
    $("#TotalValue").val(totalValue)
  })
  

});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" name="Value1" id="Value1">Value 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="125" name="Value2" id="Value2">Value 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="150" name="Value3" id="Value1">Value 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="175" name="Value4" id="Value1">Value 4
  <input type="checkbox" value="200" name="Value5" id="Value1">Value 5
</div>
Total Value :<input value="" name="TotalValue" id="TotalValue" />
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much hsnbl. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi...does the function need to go at the end right before the </html> or do I need to put it in the <head> section. I have applied your code to my actual code, but the Total Value textbox is not being populated when I click any checkbox. Thanks

Comment: @dr1054 Did you  check to console? 
you can put this jquery code into head section with <script> tag because it will work after document ready.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean did I check to console?

Comment: you can make mouse right click and then click inspect after do that you will see tabs on the new window. console is one this tabs

Comment: hsnbl...sorry, I found the problem and now it works. I already had a link to jquery version and I added the one you gave me and there was a conflict. Now I am only using your link :-)  I will accept the answer as solved. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi hsnbl. So now I need to use the value of TotalValue in a calculation with some other numbers. What would I use for the value of that textbox when adding it to other textbox values?

Comment: I did not understand question well. are you trying to aggregate textbox values with eachother

Comment: <script>
     function TotalTextBoxes() {
     var s1 = Number(TextBox1.value.replace(",",""));
     var s2 = Number(TextBox2.value.replace(",",""));
     var s2 = Number(TextBox3.value.replace(",",""));
     var s4 = Number(TextBox4.value.replace(",",""));
     document.getElementbyID("TextBoxTotal").value =   
     numberWithCommas(Number(s1 + s2 + s3 + s4));
     }
     </script>

Comment: TextBox2 is the one you helped me with. The total comes up to 0 when I use that code. So wondering how to call that value.

Comment: <script> 
     function TotalTextBoxes() { 
     var s1 = Number(TextBox1.value.replace(",","")); 
     var s2 = Number(TextBox2.value.replace(",","")); 
     var s3 = Number(TextBox3.value.replace(",","")); 
     var s4 = Number(TextBox4.value.replace(",","")); 
     document.getElementbyID("TextBoxTotal").value = 
numberWithCommas(Number(s1 + s2 + s3 + s4));
     } 
     </script>

Comment: sorry, trying to format this correctly but it is not working

Comment: can you create jsfiddle snippet to help me about understanding this situation better?

Comment: Hi ...would it be easier if I gave you URL and explained or is that not permitted on this forum?

Comment: you can easily create a sample on https://jsfiddle.net/ with your html,css and javascript code then i can undestand situation better

Comment: OK, I will create a simple example on jsfiddle. Give me about half hour. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have to do something else now...please check this in about 4 hours from now. Thank you

Comment: Hi..here is jfiddle example. First group is a group of radio buttons. Second group is the checkbox group you gave me code for. What I am trying to do is add the total of each group to get a grand total. Works fine for radio buttons. But when I add clicks on checkbox, it adds the value of the previous checkbox. You will see what I mean. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/50p6hegq/17/

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#TotalValue').on('click', function() {
    var sList = 0;

    $('#mainDiv :checked').each(function() {
      sList += parseInt(($(this).val()));
    });


    console.log(sList);

  })

});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Value1" id="Value1">Value 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="Value2" id="Value2">Value 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="Value3" id="Value1">Value 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="Value4" id="Value1">Value 4
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="Value5" id="Value1">Value 5
</div>
<button value="Total Value" name="TotalValue" id="TotalValue">Total Value</button>
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for the answer. I think I made a mistake. Actually, Total Value should be a text box (not a checkbox) that will hold the total value based on the checkboxes that are selected. Also, how does it get the number values to compute? Thanks.

Comment: Anytime!!!!!!!!